# How to run python script in Virtual Env using Powershell Script?

Tags: python, python-3.x, powershell, scheduling

I want to schedule a python script in task scheduler for which I wrote a powershell ps1 script. I wanted to activate the virtual env using the ps1 script and within the virtual env wanted to run the python script but for some reason I am unable to do so. Below is my script:

```
C:\<Python Virtual env Path>\activate.ps1;if($lastexitcode -eq 0){C:\<Python Script Path>\dm_alt.py}
```

The above script is able to instantiate the virtual env but does not run python script.
Can someone please help?
Thanks

Comment: Are you receiving some kind of error?

Comment: Nope, no error. If run it through task scheduler than it says, script ran successfully. If I try running though Powershell, I do see the virtual env but nothing happens after that

Comment: What is the value of ```$lastexitcode``` ?

Comment: I think you just dont specify path to python.exe ( like python C:/path/script.py)

Comment: I dont need to because I want to run the script in virtual env and it does instantiate i.e. I do see the virtual env getting generated when running the .ps1 directly from ps prompt but I dont see the script running.

Comment: Where do you run this snippet? In powershell? If so you just printing path of your pycsript to stdout, you are not executing it.

Comment: Then how to run it, BTW I was able to run it using .bat file but somehow could not make it work for PS